# How to clear the error message after submitting a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys The below coding was to be work fine what is the problem is after submitting a form i need to disable the Error message at the below of the each textbox of the form.o please tell me how to rectify it....

```js
function asd() {
  var res = document.forms.myForm.length;
  flag = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < res; i++) {
    if ((document.forms.myForm[i].tagName) != 'Button') {
      var x = document.forms.myForm[i].value;
      if (x == "" || x == null) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].innerHTML = "required";
        document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].style.color = "red";
        document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.background = "lightblue";

        /*flag=false;*/
      } else if (x == "text") {
        document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].innerHTML = "qwe";
        document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].style.color = "green";
        document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.background = "lightblue";

        flag = false;
      }
    }
  }

  var gen = document.getElementsByName("gender");
  if ((gen[0].checked == false) && (gen[1].checked == false)) {
    document.getElementById("WrongMsg").innerHTML = "required";
    document.getElementById("WrongMsg").style.color = "red";
    flag = false;
  }

  var c = document.getElementsByName("chec");
  if ((c[0].checked == false) && (c[1].checked == false)) {
    document.getElementById("ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "required";
    document.getElementById("ErrorMsg").style.color = "red";
    flag = false;
  }

  return flag;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
     <head>
        <title>Form Validation</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form1.css">
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class="Divstyle">
     <h1>Form Validation</h1>

        <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return asd()" onchange="reset(form)">
                FirstName:<input type="text" class="TagColor" name="fname"/><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                LastName:<input type="text" class="TagColor" name="lname"/><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                Phone Num:<input type="text" class="TagColor" name="phno"/><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                Email:<input type="email" class="TagColor" name="email"/><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                        
                            
                Select Country:
                <select class="TagColor">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="one">INDIA</option>
                    <option value="two">PAKISTAN</option>
                    <option value="three">AUSTRALLIA</option>
                </select><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                                           
                Gender: Male:<input type="radio" name="gender"/><br>
                        Female:<input type="radio" name="gender"/><br><span id="WrongMsg"></span><br><br>
                            
                            
                Language: Tamil:<input type="checkbox" name="chec"><br>
                          English:<input type="checkbox" name="chec"><br><span id="ErrorMsg"></span><br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
       </form>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: comment out all  the lines that start with `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: A good approach to do these kind of things is a PRG pattern i.e. Post-Redirect-Get. After a post to server means submit, redirect user to same view. This will refresh all the fields itself and also eliminates the case if someone reloads the page, causing multiple duplicate requests. You can easily handle this on server side. Clearing every error message after submit from client side is a bad idea imo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the else part, for the required span tags, set the innerHTML to blank and make the color as transparent.

```
if (x == "" || x == null) {
    ....
} else if (x != null) {
     document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].innerHTML = "";
     document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].style.color = "transparent";
     document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.border = "1px solid green";
     document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.background = "lightblue";
}
```

```js
function asd() {
  var res = document.forms.myForm.length;
  flag = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < res; i++) {
    if ((document.forms.myForm[i].className) == 'TagColor') {
      var x = document.forms.myForm[i].value;
      if (x == "" || x == null) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].innerHTML = "required";
        document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].style.color = "red";
        document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.background = "lightblue";

        flag=false;
      } else if (x != null) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementsByClassName("Required")[i].style.color = "transparent";
        document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.border = "1px solid green";
        document.getElementsByClassName("TagColor")[i].style.background = "lightblue";

        //flag = false;
      }
    }
  }

  var gen = document.getElementsByName("gender");
  if ((gen[0].checked == false) && (gen[1].checked == false)) {
    document.getElementById("WrongMsg").innerHTML = "required";
    document.getElementById("WrongMsg").style.color = "red";
    flag = false;
  }
  else
  {
 document.getElementById("WrongMsg").innerHTML = "";
  }

  var c = document.getElementsByName("chec");
  if ((c[0].checked == false) && (c[1].checked == false)) {
    document.getElementById("ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "required";
    document.getElementById("ErrorMsg").style.color = "red";
    flag = false;
  }
  else
  {
 document.getElementById("ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "";
  }

  return flag;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
     <head>
        <title>Form Validation</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form1.css">
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class="Divstyle">
     <h1>Form Validation</h1>

        <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return asd()" onchange="reset(form)">
                FirstName:<input type="text" class="TagColor" name="fname"/><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                LastName:<input type="text" class="TagColor" name="lname"/><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                Phone Num:<input type="text" class="TagColor" name="phno"/><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                Email:<input type="email" class="TagColor" name="email"/><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                        
                            
                Select Country:
                <select class="TagColor">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="one">INDIA</option>
                    <option value="two">PAKISTAN</option>
                    <option value="three">AUSTRALLIA</option>
                </select><br><span class="Required"></span><br>
                                           
                Gender: Male:<input type="radio" name="gender"/><br>
                        Female:<input type="radio" name="gender"/><br><span id="WrongMsg"></span><br><br>
                            
                            
                Language: Tamil:<input type="checkbox" name="chec"><br>
                          English:<input type="checkbox" name="chec"><br><span id="ErrorMsg"></span><br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
       </form>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Spidey Thank u for giving this information it was perfectly working on your snippet. But it was not work on my browser. After validating a form there was some blink will happen please suggest me to solve the problem...

Comment: Which browser are u using? Did you try disabling the addons as they can cause conflicts too?

Comment: Ya i'm currently using google chrome in windows8 version.Did u try it in your browser? and How to disable the addons please tell me the suggestion....

Comment: Check the updated snippet. Looks like the blinking issue was due to that the `for` loop was checking for radio buttons also which are not required in this case.

Comment: Hi spidey i've one more help from your side please see the exercise in the URL:http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/add-edit-and-delete-rows-from-table-dynamically-using-javascript.php                                                                  I need to add/insert data from one table and display it into another table at the same page dynamically i need a source code in a easy way so please give me a suggestion for me...

Comment: Welcome. If this answer solved your problem, accept it as an answer. If you think this was a good answer, you can upvote it too. For your new question, see this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144508/clone-and-delete-selected-row-to-another-table). You can start on the basis of this and if you get stuck, post a new question here and someone will help you out.